# Issue with pagination when filtering items

Tags: reactjs, typescript, pagination

I have website on React and I want to filter items from different pages. The problem is that it filters items only on the first page.

**Code:**

*CustomersEpolicyPage.tsx*

```
import React, {useEffect, useMemo, useState} from "react";
import {useHistory, useParams, Link} from "react-router-dom"; 
import {getCurrentUser, getCurrentUserInfo} from "../../../redux-data/user/userReducer";
import {useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {formatPhoneNumber, filterRecords, countRecords, getInsuranceTypeName, validatePhoneNumber, checkAuthToken} from "../../../utils/utilsGeneral";
import {insuranceTypes} from "../../../mock-data/insuranceTypes";
import {dbAxiosInstance} from "../../../core/configDBAxios";
import Pagination from "../../../utils/Pagination";
import webConfig from "../../../config";
import CustomLoader from "../../../components/Forms/common/CustomLoader";
import CustomTooltip from "../../../components/Forms/common/CustomTooltip";

const CustomersEpolicyPage = (props) => {
    const dashboardHistory = useHistory();
    const currentUser = useSelector(getCurrentUser);
    const currentUserInfo = useSelector(getCurrentUserInfo);
    const {id, externalID} = useParams<{
        id: string;
        externalID: string;
    }>();
    const [authInProgress, setAuthInProgress] = useState(false);
    const [customers, setCustomers] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const [customersCount, setCustomersCount] = useState(0); 
    const [recordsOnPage, setRecordsOnPage] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const [customersErrorMsg, setCustomersErrorMsg] = useState("");
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
    const epolicyType = insuranceTypes[0].value;
    const [filteredItems, setFilteredItems] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const [filterCompleted, setFilterCompleted] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const checkAdminRights = () => {
            if (checkAuthToken()) {
                if (currentUser && currentUserInfo) {
                    setAuthInProgress(false);

                    if (!currentUserInfo?.permissions.salePointAdmin) {
                        dashboardHistory.push("/");
                    }
                } else {
                    setAuthInProgress(true);
                }
            } else {
                dashboardHistory.push("/");
            }
        };

        checkAdminRights();
    }, [currentUser, currentUserInfo]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchCustomers = async () => {
            try {
                await dbAxiosInstance.get(`/customers/${encodeURIComponent(epolicyType)}`).then((res: any) => {
                    const dbCustomersData = res.data;

                    if (dbCustomersData) {
                        if (dbCustomersData.length > 0) {
                            setCustomers(dbCustomersData);
                            setFilteredItems(dbCustomersData);
                            setCustomersErrorMsg("");
                        } else {
                            setCustomers([]);
                            setFilteredItems([]);
                            setCustomersErrorMsg("Немає доданих даних клієнтів. Натисніть на кнопку, щоб додати дані клієнта.");
                        }
                    } else {
                        setCustomers([]);
                        setFilteredItems([]);
                        setCustomersErrorMsg("Помилка БД! Не вдалося завантажити дані клієнтів.");
                    }
                }).catch((error: any) => {
                    const userDataError = error.toJSON();
                    setCustomersErrorMsg(error.response!.data!.message || userDataError.message || "Unknown error");
                    setCustomers([]);
                    setFilteredItems([]);
                });
            } catch (error: any) {
                setCustomers([]);
                setFilteredItems([]);
                setCustomersErrorMsg("Помилка БД! Не вдалося завантажити дані клієнтів.");
            }
        };

        const countCustomers = async () => {
            try {
                await dbAxiosInstance.get(`/count-customers/${encodeURIComponent(epolicyType)}`).then((res: any) => {
                    const dbCountCustomersData = res.data;

                    if (dbCountCustomersData) {
                        if (dbCountCustomersData.length > 0) {
                            setCustomersCount(dbCountCustomersData[0].counter);
                        } else {
                            setCustomersCount(0);
                        }
                    } else {
                        setCustomersCount(0);
                    }
                }).catch((error: any) => {
                    setCustomersCount(0);
                });
            } catch (error: any) {
                setCustomersCount(0);
            }
        };

        fetchCustomers();
        countCustomers();
    }, []);

    const handleItemDelete = async (id) => {
        await dbAxiosInstance.delete(`/customer/${encodeURIComponent(id)}`).then((res: any) => {
            setRecordsOnPage(filterRecords(recordsOnPage, id));
            const allRecords = countRecords(customersCount);
            setCustomersCount(allRecords);

            if (allRecords === 0) {
                setCustomersErrorMsg("Немає доданих даних клієнтів. Натисніть на кнопку, щоб додати дані клієнта.");
            }
        }).catch((error: any) => {
            const userDataError = error.toJSON();
            setCustomersErrorMsg(error.response!.data!.message || userDataError.message || "Unknown error");
            setCustomers([]);
        });
    };

    const handleRecordsOnPage = (records) => {
        console.log("Records: ", records, "Records length: ", records.length);
        setRecordsOnPage(records);
    };

    const navToAddCustomersPage = (event) => {
        dashboardHistory.push({pathname: `/admin/dashboard/${id}/${externalID}/add-customer/${epolicyType}`});
    };

    const handleSearchChange = (event) => {
        setFilterCompleted(false);
        setSearch(event.target.value);
    };

    useMemo(() => {
        const updatedFilteredItems = customers.filter(item => {
            return Object.values(item).some((value: any) =>
                value?.toString().includes(search)
            );
        });
        setFilteredItems(updatedFilteredItems);
    }, [customers, search]);

    const resetSearch = () => {
        if (search) {
            setSearch("");
            setFilteredItems(customers);
            setFilterCompleted(false);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="section-white">
                {authInProgress ?
                    <CustomLoader className="auth-request" isSquare={false} isInfoOn={true} isLoading={authInProgress} infoMsg="Триває перевірка авторизації" />
                 :
                  <>
                    <div className="back-icon">
                        <CustomTooltip msg="Назад"><a onClick={dashboardHistory.goBack}><i className="fa-regular fa-arrow-left"></i></a></CustomTooltip>
                    </div>
                    <div className="dashboard-container">
                        <h1><CustomTooltip msg="Перейти на Панель керування"><Link to={{pathname: `/admin/dashboard/${id}/${externalID}`}}><i className="fa-solid fa-house-chimney-user notification-icon"></i>Панель керування</Link></CustomTooltip> &laquo;&nbsp;
                            <CustomTooltip msg="Перейти до Клієнтів"><Link to={{pathname: `/admin/dashboard/${id}/${externalID}/customers`}}>Клієнти</Link></CustomTooltip> &laquo; Автоцивілка</h1>
                        <div className="itemsCounter">
                            <button type="button" className="admin-btn" onClick={navToAddCustomersPage}><i className="fa fa-plus notification-icon"></i>Додати клієнта</button>
                            <p>Клієнтів ({getInsuranceTypeName(epolicyType)}): <span className="font-bold">{customersCount}</span></p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="search-items-wrapper">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Введіть дані клієнта для пошуку..." value={search} onChange={handleSearchChange} />
                            <CustomTooltip msg="Очистити"><i className="fa-solid fa-xmark clear-search-icon" onClick={resetSearch}></i></CustomTooltip>
                        </div>
                        {customers.length > 0 && recordsOnPage.length === 0 && <div className="admin-error-notification">За Вашим запитом такого клієнта не знайдено!</div>}
                        <div className="dashboard">
                            {customers.length > 0 && customersCount > 0 ?
                                <div className="customers-wrapper">
                                    <table className="customers">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>ID</th>
                                            <th>Телефон</th>
                                            <th>Email</th>
                                            <th>Прізвище</th>
                                            <th>Iм'я</th>
                                            <th>По батькові</th>
                                            <th>Управління</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        {recordsOnPage.length > 0 && recordsOnPage.map((customer, index) => 
                                            <tr key={index}>
                                                <td>{customer.id}</td>
                                                <td><CustomTooltip msg="Натисність, щоб переглянути деталі клієнта"><Link to={{pathname: `/admin/dashboard/${id}/${externalID}/customer/${epolicyType}/${validatePhoneNumber(customer.phone_number)}/${customer.id}/view`}}>{formatPhoneNumber(customer.phone_number)}</Link></CustomTooltip></td>
                                                <td><CustomTooltip msg="Натисність, щоб переглянути деталі клієнта"><Link to={{pathname: `/admin/dashboard/${id}/${externalID}/customer/${epolicyType}/${validatePhoneNumber(customer.phone_number)}/${customer.id}/view`}}>{customer.email}</Link></CustomTooltip></td>
                                                <td><CustomTooltip msg="Натисність, щоб переглянути деталі клієнта"><Link to={{pathname: `/admin/dashboard/${id}/${externalID}/customer/${epolicyType}/${validatePhoneNumber(customer.phone_number)}/${customer.id}/view`}}>{customer.last_name}</Link></CustomTooltip></td>
                                                <td><CustomTooltip msg="Натисність, щоб переглянути деталі клієнта"><Link to={{pathname: `/admin/dashboard/${id}/${externalID}/customer/${epolicyType}/${validatePhoneNumber(customer.phone_number)}/${customer.id}/view`}}>{customer.first_name}</Link></CustomTooltip></td>
                                                <td><CustomTooltip msg="Натисність, щоб переглянути деталі клієнта"><Link to={{pathname: `/admin/dashboard/${id}/${externalID}/customer/${epolicyType}/${validatePhoneNumber(customer.phone_number)}/${customer.id}/view`}}>{customer.middle_name}</Link></CustomTooltip></td>
                                                <td>
                                                <div className="manage-item-container">
                                                        <CustomTooltip msg="Редагувати">
                                                            <Link className="edit-item" to={{pathname: `/admin/dashboard/${id}/${externalID}/customer/${epolicyType}/${validatePhoneNumber(customer.phone_number)}/${customer.id}/edit`}}>
                                                                <i className="fa fa-pencil-alt"></i>
                                                            </Link>
                                                        </CustomTooltip>
                                                        <CustomTooltip msg="Переглянути деталі клієнта">
                                                            <Link className="view-item" to={{pathname: `/admin/dashboard/${id}/${externalID}/customer/${epolicyType}/${validatePhoneNumber(customer.phone_number)}/${customer.id}/view`}}>
                                                                <i className="fa fa-circle-info"></i>
                                                            </Link>
                                                        </CustomTooltip>
                                                        <CustomTooltip msg="Видалити"><a className="delete-item" onClick={() => handleItemDelete(customer.id)}><i className="fa fa-trash"></i></a></CustomTooltip>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        )}
                                    </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <Pagination data={filteredItems} recordsPerPage={Number(webConfig.contentPerPage)} dataOnPage={handleRecordsOnPage} isDataLoaded={filterCompleted} setDataLoaded={(state) => setFilterCompleted(state)} />
                                </div>
                              : <div>
                                    <div className="dashboard-item">
                                        <CustomTooltip msg="Додати"><Link to={{pathname: `/admin/dashboard/${id}/${externalID}/add-customer`}}><i className="fa fa-plus"></i></Link></CustomTooltip>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="no-dashboard-item">{customersErrorMsg}</div>
                                </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </>
                }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default CustomersEpolicyPage;
```

*Pagination.tsx*

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

interface PaginationProps {
    data: any[];
    recordsPerPage: number;
    dataOnPage: any;
    isDataLoaded?: boolean;
    setDataLoaded?: any;
};

const Pagination = ({data, recordsPerPage, dataOnPage, isDataLoaded, setDataLoaded}: PaginationProps) => {
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const lastIndex = currentPage * recordsPerPage;
    const firstIndex = lastIndex - recordsPerPage;
    console.log(data);
    const records = data.slice(firstIndex, lastIndex);
    const numPages = Math.ceil(data.length / recordsPerPage);
    const numbers = Array.from({length: numPages}, (_, i) => i + 1);

    const prevPage = () => {
        if (currentPage !== 1) {
            setDataLoaded(false);
            setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1);
        }
    };

    const changeCurrentPage = (pageNum) => {
        if (currentPage !== pageNum) {
            setDataLoaded(false);
            setCurrentPage(pageNum);
        }
    };

    const nextPage = () => {
        if (currentPage !== numPages) {
            setDataLoaded(false);
            setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
        }
    };

    if (!isDataLoaded && records.length > 0) {
        dataOnPage(records);
        setDataLoaded(true);
    }

    return (
        <>
        {records && records.length > 0 &&
            <div className="pagination-wrapper">
                <ul className="pagination-container">
                { 
                    currentPage !== 1 &&
                    <li className="pagination-page-item">
                        <a className="pagination-page-link" onClick={prevPage}>Попередня</a>
                    </li>
                }
                {
                    numbers.length > 1 && numbers.map((number, index) =>
                        <li className={`pagination-page-item ${currentPage === number ? "active" : ""}`} key={index}>
                            <a className="pagination-page-link" onClick={() => changeCurrentPage(number)}>{number}</a>
                        </li>
                    )
                }
                {
                    currentPage !== numPages &&
                    <li className="pagination-page-item">
                        <a className="pagination-page-link" onClick={nextPage}>Наступна</a>
                    </li>
                }
                </ul>
            </div>
        }
        </>
    );
};

export default Pagination;
```

**Screenshot:** https://i.ibb.co/55Xkw0W/Filter-issue.gif

As you can see on the screenshot, I can filter data only on the 1st page but when I am on the 2nd/3rd page, then filter is not working. Any ideas how to fix this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I have fixed this issue by improving the `Pagination` component. Now, it gets records for the current page by calling: `getRecordsForCurrentPage()` method.

**Pagination.tsx:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

interface PaginationProps {
    data: any[];
    recordsPerPage: number;
    dataOnPage: any;
    isDataLoaded: boolean;
    setDataLoaded: (state: boolean) => void;
    isFilterProcessing: boolean;
    setFilterState: (state: boolean) => void;
};

const Pagination = ({data, recordsPerPage, dataOnPage, isDataLoaded, setDataLoaded, isFilterProcessing, setFilterState}: PaginationProps) => {
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const numPages = Math.ceil(data.length / recordsPerPage);
    console.log("Data: ", data);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isDataLoaded) {
            console.log("Executing....");
            dataOnPage(getRecordsForCurrentPage());

            if (data.length > 0) {
                setDataLoaded(true);
            }

            if (isFilterProcessing) {
                setCurrentPage(1);
                setFilterState(false);
            }
        }
    }, [data, currentPage, isDataLoaded]);

    const getRecordsForCurrentPage = () => {
        const lastIndex = currentPage * recordsPerPage;
        const firstIndex = lastIndex - recordsPerPage;
        return data.slice(firstIndex, lastIndex);
    };

    const goToPage = (pageNum: number) => {
        if (currentPage !== pageNum) {
            setDataLoaded(false);
            setCurrentPage(pageNum);
        }
    };

    const prevPage = () => {
        if (currentPage > 1) {
            goToPage(currentPage - 1);
        }
    };

    const nextPage = () => {
        if (currentPage < numPages) {
            goToPage(currentPage + 1);
        }
    };

    const renderPagination = () => {
        const pages = Array.from({length: numPages}, (_, i) => i + 1);

        return (
            <ul className="pagination-container">
                {currentPage !== 1 && pages.length > 0 && (
                    <li className="pagination-page-item">
                        <a className="pagination-page-link" onClick={prevPage}>Попередня</a>
                    </li>
                )}
                {pages.length > 0 && pages.map((number) => (
                    <li className={`pagination-page-item ${currentPage === number ? "active" : ""}`} key={number}>
                        <a className="pagination-page-link" onClick={() => goToPage(number)}>{number}</a>
                    </li>
                ))}
                {currentPage !== numPages && pages.length > 0 && (
                    <li className="pagination-page-item">
                        <a className="pagination-page-link" onClick={nextPage}>Наступна</a>
                    </li>
                )}
            </ul>
        );
    };

    return (
        <div className="pagination-wrapper">
            {renderPagination()}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Pagination;
```

Additionally, I added `processingFilter` state to `CustomersEpolicyPage` component and set it to `setProcessingFilter(true);` in `handleSearchChange` method when filtering items. I pass `processingFilter` as a property to the `Pagination` component. In `Pagination` component I am checking for `isFilterProcessing` and setting current page to be 1. So, it will always switch to the first page to get the result.

**CustomersEpolicyPage.tsx:**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {useHistory, useParams, Link} from "react-router-dom"; 
import {getCurrentUser, getCurrentUserInfo} from "../../../redux-data/user/userReducer";
import {useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {formatPhoneNumber, filterRecords, countRecords, getInsuranceTypeName, validatePhoneNumber, checkAuthToken} from "../../../utils/utilsGeneral";
import {insuranceTypes} from "../../../mock-data/insuranceTypes";
import {dbAxiosInstance} from "../../../core/configDBAxios";
import Pagination from "../../../utils/Pagination";
import webConfig from "../../../config";
import CustomLoader from "../../../components/Forms/common/CustomLoader";
import CustomTooltip from "../../../components/Forms/common/CustomTooltip";

const CustomersEpolicyPage = (props) => {
    const dashboardHistory = useHistory();
    const currentUser = useSelector(getCurrentUser);
    const currentUserInfo = useSelector(getCurrentUserInfo);
    const {id, externalID} = useParams<{
        id: string;
        externalID: string;
    }>();
    const [authInProgress, setAuthInProgress] = useState(false);
    const [customers, setCustomers] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const [customersCount, setCustomersCount] = useState(0); 
    const [recordsOnPage, setRecordsOnPage] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const [customersErrorMsg, setCustomersErrorMsg] = useState("");
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
    const epolicyType = insuranceTypes[0].value;
    const [filteredItems, setFilteredItems] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const [filterCompleted, setFilterCompleted] = useState(false);
    const [processingFilter, setProcessingFilter] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const checkAdminRights = () => {
            if (checkAuthToken()) {
                if (currentUser && currentUserInfo) {
                    setAuthInProgress(false);

                    if (!currentUserInfo?.permissions.salePointAdmin) {
                        dashboardHistory.push("/");
                    }
                } else {
                    setAuthInProgress(true);
                }
            } else {
                dashboardHistory.push("/");
            }
        };

        checkAdminRights();
    }, [currentUser, currentUserInfo]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchCustomers = async () => {
            try {
                await dbAxiosInstance.get(`/customers/${encodeURIComponent(epolicyType)}`).then((res: any) => {
                    const dbCustomersData = res.data;

                    if (dbCustomersData) {
                        if (dbCustomersData.length > 0) {
                            setCustomers(dbCustomersData);
                            setFilteredItems(dbCustomersData);
                            setCustomersErrorMsg("");
                        } else {
                            setCustomers([]);
                            setFilteredItems([]);
                            setCustomersErrorMsg("Немає доданих даних клієнтів. Натисніть на кнопку, щоб додати дані клієнта.");
                        }
                    } else {
                        setCustomers([]);
                        setFilteredItems([]);
                        setCustomersErrorMsg("Помилка БД! Не вдалося завантажити дані клієнтів.");
                    }
                }).catch((error: any) => {
                    const userDataError = error.toJSON();
                    setCustomersErrorMsg(error.response!.data!.message || userDataError.message || "Unknown error");
                    setCustomers([]);
                    setFilteredItems([]);
                });
            } catch (error: any) {
                setCustomers([]);
                setFilteredItems([]);
                setCustomersErrorMsg("Помилка БД! Не вдалося завантажити дані клієнтів.");
            }
        };

        const countCustomers = async () => {
            try {
                await dbAxiosInstance.get(`/count-customers/${encodeURIComponent(epolicyType)}`).then((res: any) => {
                    const dbCountCustomersData = res.data;

                    if (dbCountCustomersData) {
                        if (dbCountCustomersData.length > 0) {
                            setCustomersCount(dbCountCustomersData[0].counter);
                        } else {
                            setCustomersCount(0);
                        }
                    } else {
                        setCustomersCount(0);
                    }
                }).catch((error: any) => {
                    setCustomersCount(0);
                });
            } catch (error: any) {
                setCustomersCount(0);
            }
        };

        fetchCustomers();
        countCustomers();
    }, []);

    const handleItemDelete = async (id) => {
        await dbAxiosInstance.delete(`/customer/${encodeURIComponent(id)}`).then((res: any) => {
            setRecordsOnPage(filterRecords(recordsOnPage, id));
            const allRecords = countRecords(customersCount);
            setCustomersCount(allRecords);

            if (allRecords === 0) {
                setCustomersErrorMsg("Немає доданих даних клієнтів. Натисніть на кнопку, щоб додати дані клієнта.");
            }
        }).catch((error: any) => {
            const userDataError = error.toJSON();
            setCustomersErrorMsg(error.response!.data!.message || userDataError.message || "Unknown error");
            setCustomers([]);
        });
    };

    const handleRecordsOnPage = (records) => {
        console.log("Records: ", records, "Records length: ", records.length);
        setRecordsOnPage(records);
    };

    const navToAddCustomersPage = (event) => {
        dashboardHistory.push({pathname: `/admin/dashboard/${id}/${externalID}/add-customer/${epolicyType}`});
    };

    const handleSearchChange = (event) => {
        setFilterCompleted(false);
        const searchData = event.target.value;
        setSearch(searchData);
        setProcessingFilter(true);
        const updatedFilteredItems = customers.filter(item => {
            return Object.values(item).some((value: any) =>
                value?.toString().includes(searchData)
            );
        });
        setFilteredItems(updatedFilteredItems);
    };

    const resetSearch = () => {
        if (search) {
            setSearch("");
            setFilteredItems(customers);
            setFilterCompleted(false);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="section-white">
                {authInProgress ?
                    <CustomLoader className="auth-request" isSquare={false} isInfoOn={true} isLoading={authInProgress} infoMsg="Триває перевірка авторизації" />
                 :
                  <>
                    <div className="back-icon">
                        <CustomTooltip msg="Назад"><a onClick={dashboardHistory.goBack}><i className="fa-regular fa-arrow-left"></i></a></CustomTooltip>
                    </div>
                    <div className="dashboard-container">
                        <h1><CustomTooltip msg="Перейти на Панель керування"><Link to={{pathname: `/admin/dashboard/${id}/${externalID}`}}><i className="fa-solid fa-house-chimney-user notification-icon"></i>Панель керування</Link></CustomTooltip> &laquo;&nbsp;
                            <CustomTooltip msg="Перейти до Клієнтів"><Link to={{pathname: `/admin/dashboard/${id}/${externalID}/customers`}}>Клієнти</Link></CustomTooltip> &laquo; Автоцивілка</h1>
                        <div className="itemsCounter">
                            <button type="button" className="admin-btn" onClick={navToAddCustomersPage}><i className="fa fa-plus notification-icon"></i>Додати клієнта</button>
                            <p>Клієнтів ({getInsuranceTypeName(epolicyType)}): <span className="font-bold">{customersCount}</span></p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="search-items-wrapper">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Введіть дані клієнта для пошуку..." value={search} onChange={handleSearchChange} />
                            <CustomTooltip msg="Очистити"><i className="fa-solid fa-xmark clear-search-icon" onClick={resetSearch}></i></CustomTooltip>
                        </div>
                        {customers.length > 0 && recordsOnPage.length === 0 && <div className="admin-error-notification">За Вашим запитом такого клієнта не знайдено!</div>}
                        <div className="dashboard">
                            {customers.length > 0 && customersCount > 0 ?
                                <div className="customers-wrapper">
                                    <table className="customers">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>ID</th>
                                            <th>Телефон</th>
                                            <th>Email</th>
                                            <th>Прізвище</th>
                                            <th>Iм'я</th>
                                            <th>По батькові</th>
                                            <th>Управління</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        {recordsOnPage.length > 0 && recordsOnPage.map((customer, index) => 
                                            <tr key={index}>
                                                <td>{customer.id}</td>
                                                <td><CustomTooltip msg="Натисність, щоб переглянути деталі клієнта"><Link to={{pathname: `/admin/dashboard/${id}/${externalID}/customer/${epolicyType}/${validatePhoneNumber(customer.phone_number)}/${customer.id}/view`}}>{formatPhoneNumber(customer.phone_number)}</Link></CustomTooltip></td>
                                                <td><CustomTooltip msg="Натисність, щоб переглянути деталі клієнта"><Link to={{pathname: `/admin/dashboard/${id}/${externalID}/customer/${epolicyType}/${validatePhoneNumber(customer.phone_number)}/${customer.id}/view`}}>{customer.email}</Link></CustomTooltip></td>
                                                <td><CustomTooltip msg="Натисність, щоб переглянути деталі клієнта"><Link to={{pathname: `/admin/dashboard/${id}/${externalID}/customer/${epolicyType}/${validatePhoneNumber(customer.phone_number)}/${customer.id}/view`}}>{customer.last_name}</Link></CustomTooltip></td>
                                                <td><CustomTooltip msg="Натисність, щоб переглянути деталі клієнта"><Link to={{pathname: `/admin/dashboard/${id}/${externalID}/customer/${epolicyType}/${validatePhoneNumber(customer.phone_number)}/${customer.id}/view`}}>{customer.first_name}</Link></CustomTooltip></td>
                                                <td><CustomTooltip msg="Натисність, щоб переглянути деталі клієнта"><Link to={{pathname: `/admin/dashboard/${id}/${externalID}/customer/${epolicyType}/${validatePhoneNumber(customer.phone_number)}/${customer.id}/view`}}>{customer.middle_name}</Link></CustomTooltip></td>
                                                <td>
                                                <div className="manage-item-container">
                                                        <CustomTooltip msg="Редагувати">
                                                            <Link className="edit-item" to={{pathname: `/admin/dashboard/${id}/${externalID}/customer/${epolicyType}/${validatePhoneNumber(customer.phone_number)}/${customer.id}/edit`}}>
                                                                <i className="fa fa-pencil-alt"></i>
                                                            </Link>
                                                        </CustomTooltip>
                                                        <CustomTooltip msg="Переглянути деталі клієнта">
                                                            <Link className="view-item" to={{pathname: `/admin/dashboard/${id}/${externalID}/customer/${epolicyType}/${validatePhoneNumber(customer.phone_number)}/${customer.id}/view`}}>
                                                                <i className="fa fa-circle-info"></i>
                                                            </Link>
                                                        </CustomTooltip>
                                                        <CustomTooltip msg="Видалити"><a className="delete-item" onClick={() => handleItemDelete(customer.id)}><i className="fa fa-trash"></i></a></CustomTooltip>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        )}
                                    </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <Pagination data={filteredItems} recordsPerPage={Number(webConfig.contentPerPage)} dataOnPage={handleRecordsOnPage} isDataLoaded={filterCompleted} setDataLoaded={(state) => setFilterCompleted(state)} isFilterProcessing={processingFilter} setFilterState={(state) => setProcessingFilter(state)} />
                                </div>
                              : <div>
                                    <div className="dashboard-item">
                                        <CustomTooltip msg="Додати"><Link to={{pathname: `/admin/dashboard/${id}/${externalID}/add-customer`}}><i className="fa fa-plus"></i></Link></CustomTooltip>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="no-dashboard-item">{customersErrorMsg}</div>
                                </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </>
                }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default CustomersEpolicyPage;
```

Now, it works well. The issue is resolved. Thank you.